# code/website to generate stacked bar graph in jsp

Tags: jsp

hi all
can any one provide me the code/website name from where i can get jsp source code to generate stacked bar graph and other graphs.it will be good if code is in jsp .

Thanks
Yugal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one on RoseIndia's site that shows how to create area chart in JSP  http://www.roseindia.net/chartgraphs/areachart-jsppage.shtml

Now, just replace the charting code with the one for making bar charts and you are done: http://www.geodaq.com/jfreechart-sample/bar_chart_code.jsp